# PHP - Get path by searching array tree by another multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

My question is similar to [Searching for an array key branch inside a larger array tree - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13692816/104419), but for different limitations (like processing on the fly, etc) and why not for knowledge sake I would like to implement it using just PHP recursion.

Consider this data:

```
array(
    'root_trrreeee1' => array(
        'path1' => array(
            'description' => 'etc',
            'child_of_path_1' => array(
                array('name' => '1'),
                array('name' => '1')
            )
        ),
        'path1' => array(
            'description' => 'etc',
            'child_of_path_1' => array(
                array('name' => '1'),
                array('name' => '1')
            )
        ),
    ),
    'name' => '1',
    1 => array('name' => '1'),
    'another_leaf' => '1'
)
```

If I search for `array('name' => '1')` it should return the path I need to traverse to get to that value `root_trrreeee1.path1.child_of_path_1.o`, preferably returned as array:

```
array(
    0 => root_trrreeee1
    1 => path1
    2 => child_of_path_1
    3 => 0
)
```

This is the recursive function I've tried to implement but its not working:

```
function multidimensional_preserv_key_search($haystack, $needle, $path = array(), &$true_path = array())
{
    if (empty($needle) || empty($haystack)) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {

        foreach ($needle as $skey => $svalue) {

            if (is_array($value)) {
                $path = multidimensional_preserv_key_search($value, $needle, array($key => $path), $true_path);
            }

            if (($value === $svalue) && ($key === $skey)) {
                $true_path = $path;
                return $true_path;
            }
        }

    }

    if (is_array($true_path)) { return array_reverse(flatten_keys($true_path)); }
    return $path;
}


function flatten_keys($array)
{
    $result = array();

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            $result[] = $key;
            $result = array_merge($result, self::flatten_keys($value));
        } else {
            $result[] = $key;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

it returns just an empty array.
Thanks in advance.

Similar questions I've found:

- [Searching for an array key branch inside a larger array tree - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692816/searching-for-an-array-key-branch-inside-a-larger-array-tree-php)
- [Find a value & key in a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891209/find-a-value-key-in-a-multidimensional-array?lq=1)
- [Find all second level keys in multi-dimensional array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455758/find-all-second-level-keys-in-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)
- [Find an array inside another larger array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940194/find-an-array-inside-another-larger-array)
- [How to search by key=>value in a multidimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019076/how-to-search-by-key-value-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php?rq=1)
- [Searching for a key in a multidimensional array then changing a value with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416812/searching-for-a-key-in-a-multidimensional-array-then-changing-a-value-with-php)
- [How can I find the locations of an item in a Python list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853023/how-can-i-find-the-locations-of-an-item-in-a-python-list-of-lists)

Comment: have you got any solutions. i am stuck on the same point

Comment: I implemented a custom Backtracking Algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking (code on the page)

Comment: For those having the same problem, its called **Backtracking** (as in algorithm). There is a working pseudo-code on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

Answer (score 0):

This recursive function searches for the first occurrence of a value in a multidimensional array and returns the path to it as an array of keys.

```
function array_value_path($array, $needle, &$path)
{
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == $needle || is_array($value) && array_value_path($value, $needle, $path)) {
            array_unshift($path, $key);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

[fiddle](https://3v4l.org/mWjBO)

```
array_value_path($a, ['name' => 1], $path);

Array
(
    [0] => root_trrreeee1
    [1] => path1
    [2] => child_of_path_1
    [3] => 0
)

array_value_path($a, 1, $path);

Array
(
    [0] => root_trrreeee1
    [1] => path1
    [2] => child_of_path_1
    [3] => 0
    [4] => name
)
```